# jDBI and H2 not playing nicely with escaping `<`

Tags: java, h2, jdbi

I have a query in my `@SqlUpdate` that uses a `<` character so this is escaped:

```
@SqlUpdate(
    "... DateCreated \\< (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) ..."
)
```

This works fine in my real production env, but when I try to run a test for it using H2 in-memory database, I get

> org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToCreateStatementException:
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement

How do I fix this?

Comment: What database vendor is your production environment? It's possible that escaping in `\\<` is not supported by H2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too.
Put one back slash worked for me.
`...DateCreated \< (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)...`
Don't know if JDBI can support it in some other way, this workaround is not nice.